# Graph not showing properly in page in shiny

Tags: r, plot, shiny

I am new to shiny and i have the following problem. My plot doesn't show up in the whole page. I searched about the fillPage and fluidPage but i couldn't make any progress.  My code is the following:

```
library(shiny)
library(demography)
library(shinythemes)


ui <-fillPage(


titlePanel("Mortality"),


 sidebarLayout(


sidebarPanel(
  

  selectInput(inputId = "dataset",
              label = "Choose a dataset:",
              choices = c( "Austria","Belgium","Bulgaria","Czech Republic","Denmark","Finland","France","Germany","Greece","Iceland","Italy","Luxembourg","Netherlands","Portugal","Spain","Sweden","Switzerland","U.K","Ukraine"))
  
 
  
),


mainPanel(
  
  
  textOutput("caption", container = span),
  
 
  verbatimTextOutput("summary"),
  
  
 
  plotOutput('plot')
 
    )
    )
   )
    server <- function(input, output) {




 Austria=hmd.mx("AUT",, , "AUT")

datasetInput <- reactive({
    switch(input$dataset,
       "Austria"=Austria,
       "Belgium"=Belgium,
       "Bulgaria"=Bulgaria,
       "Czech Republic"=Czech.Republic,
       "Denmark"=Denmark,
       "Finland"=Finland,
       "France"=France,
       "Germany"=Germany,
       "Greece"=Greece,
       "Iceland"=Iceland,
       "Italy"=Italy,
       "Luxembourg"=Luxembourg,
       "Netherlands"=Netherlands,
       "Portugal"=Portugal,
       "Spain"=Spain,
       "Sweden"=Sweden,
       "Switzerland"=Switzerland,
       "U.K"=U.K)
   })


  output$caption <- renderText({
    input$dataset
   })


  output$summary <- renderPrint({
    dataset <- datasetInput()
   summary(dataset)
  })
 

 output$plot <- renderPlot({
   dataset <- datasetInput()
   plot(dataset)
   })

   }


  shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Here is a screenshot.
Thank you for your time [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q30OF.png)

PS. In my code i have data from other countries, not only Austria

Comment: I run your code (with creating HMD account) and got no problems.
[like this:](https://imgur.com/a/X1QvM3g)
Is your shiny library up to date?

Answer (score 0):

Try fillPage height

> fillPage(plotOutput("plot", height = "100%"))